# UIKeyboard pushing UIWEBVIEW

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiwebview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

Currently the way ios handles input fields in the uiwebviews is by pushing the uiwebview up when u tap on the input field in a uiwebview. Sometimes, the uiwebview goes outside the page. I was wondering how the whole things work? My parentviewcontroller doesn't have any scrollview inside etc.. but yet it pushes the uiwebview up.

Any idea how I can prevent the keyboard from pushing the uiwebview up. How does it know by how much it needs to push up. I added a method to get the information about the keybaord when it shows up and the size of the keyboard which is returned is 1024px for the height which is really weird.

Thanks.

Comment: I know it was along time ago but by any chance, did you find any solution for this?